# No terminal messages from tor 4.5.1

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, ubuntu

After downloading the last release of tor (4.5.1), terminal messages do not appear anymore. The usual stuff tor used to tell me when ran from terminal is not there - stuff like "Tor can't help you if you use it wrong......", or "Opening control listener on 127.0.0.1:9151", or "Tor browser exited cleanly", or info saying that the circuit has been established, or how many % of guards, midpoints and exits have been found, nothing at all, nothing. Why is that? Does anyone know?
I'm running LUbuntu
I should also add that before 4.5.1 release I ran tor from terminal and not as root and I do so exactly the same way now, the difference is there is no feedback from tor...

Comment: you can get those messages back by adding "--verbose".

Comment: I'll try that, cheers.